# How to replace a value in shell script

Tags: xcode, shell, sh, jenkins-scriptler

I am beginner in shell script, I have a string like **${VERSION_NUMBER}${VERSION_SUFFIX}** here i would like to replace **${VERSION_NUMBER}** with my own value like 1200 kind of. can you suggest me ?

Comment: I heard that one for text in files , as i am beginner i do not have clear idea , can you suggest with simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
s='${VERSION_NUMBER}${VERSION_SUFFIX}'
sed 's/\${VERSION_NUMBER}/1200/' <<< "$s"
1200${VERSION_SUFFIX}
```

Comment: Thanks , It worked for me , can you explain what does it really mean  **<<< "$s"** and how could I access  sed result

Comment: `<<<` is called here-doc. That is used to feed a value to sed command.

Comment: Thanks , How can we pass a variable value in place of 1200 and how we can store sed result in one variable , can you write as above in few lines , that could help me alot

Comment: Then you can do: `n=1500; sed "s/\${VERSION_NUMBER}/$n/" <<< "$s"`

Comment: How can retrieve sed result

Comment: You can do: `out=$(sed "s/\${VERSION_NUMBER}/$n/" <<< "$s")` to store `sed's` output

Answer (score 0):

```
myvar=4000
s='${VERSION_NUMBER}${VERSION_SUFFIX}'
s=`echo $s | sed 's/\${VERSION_NUMBER}/'"$myvar"'/g'`
echo $s
```

u will get output as 4000${VERSION_SUFFIX}

Comment: I have a value in Variable not in file , can you suggest

Comment: VERSION_NUMBER=1200, the variable will contain value 1200 in it. Please provide some sample example.

Comment: s='${VERSION_NUMBER}${VERSION_SUFFIX}' I have this string i want replace a variable in ${VERSION_NUMBER} place

Comment: I have modified my answer please verify.

Comment: ** ` **echo $s | sed -i 's/\${VERSION_NUMBER}/'"$myvar"'/g' ** ` ** , what does it really means , If i remove these quotes output as     echo $s | sed s/${VERSION_NUMBER}/"$myvar"/g

Comment: echo $s | sed s/${VERSION_NUMBER}/"$myvar"/g this will also work. But I have used HP-UX Unix system, on that we have some limitations. The meaning is just that  you have printed the value of s via echo then through pipe '|' you have transferred the printed output to sed. sed replaced the value ${VERSION_NUMBER} to value of myvar.

Comment: I want to use that result as well  4000${VERSION_SUFFIX} , How could we ?

Comment: Means now we have variable s containing 4000${VERSION_SUFFIX} meaning s=4000${VERSION_SUFFIX}; let suppose ${VERSION_SUFFIX}=kilo and we have 4000kilo=40 then we have to get value 40 in the end or we need value 4000kilo as last value???

Comment: myvar=4000
s='${VERSION_NUMBER}${VERSION_SUFFIX}'
echo $s | sed 's/\${VERSION_NUMBER}/'"$myvar"'/g'
echo $s   If i write like this output as 4000${VERSION_SUFFIX}
${VERSION_NUMBER}${VERSION_SUFFIX} but my doubt is output should be same for two echos right?

Comment: No the output of both echo is not same. As in first echo old value of s is printed and sent to sed. The first echo line is used within expression `` so it will return value executed between `` and it will be stored again in variable s. So the first echo will not print in prompt. First echo output is captured by sed command after pipe |. Second echo will only print. Please refer my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways do the same.

1. One of the methods is using sed. Most of the people already mentioned above.
2. We can use tr command.

   ```
   cat file_name | tr VERSION_NUMBER REQUIRED_VERSION > resultant_file_name
   ```
3. Open the file in vim editor. Keep the file in insert mode and execute the following command.

   ```
   %s/VERSION_NUMBER/REQUIRED_VERSION/g
   ```